# size class not take effect on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, size-classes

My project need adapt iPhone and iPad,but we cannot use storyboard for some reason,so we create some xib file,but when I run in iPad,I find that size class in xib is not effect,no matter  (w Any h Regular) or (w Regular h Regular),and my iPad system version is 8.4.1,can anyone help me?

Comment: is your project Universal?@gavinHe

Comment: @Madhu，I check my project by this step: General ->Deployment Info -> Devices,and here is Universal,so I think this is no problem.

Comment: have you created separate xibs for ipad and iphone or you are using autolayout?@gavinHe

Comment: I use single xib by autolayout,and I find that,when my xib named test.xib,then I enter bundle directory,test.xib is built to be test.nib and test~iphone.nib,but when I used storyboard,it was built to be test.nib,test~iphone.nib and test~ipad.nib, so I am really confused